# Filtering nested dictionaries based on a criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have the following dictionary.

```
Filme = {'1': {'Titel': 'Titanic', 'Jahr': 1997, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 30, 'Schauspielern': ["Leonardo Dicaprio", "Kate Winslet", "Gloria Stuart"]},
         '2': {'Titel': 'Pulp Fiction', 'Jahr': 1994, 'Wertung': 9, 'Preis': 40, 'Schauspielern': ["Uma Thurman","John Travolta","Quentin Tarantion"]},
         '3': {'Titel': 'Wings of Desire', 'Jahr': 1987, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 40, 'Schauspielern': ["Bruno Ganz","Peter Falk","Otto Sander"]},
         '4': {'Titel': 'London Has Fallen', 'Jahr': 2016, 'Wertung': 6, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ["Gerald Butler","Morgan Freeman","Aaron Eckhart"]},
         '5': {'Titel': 'Avatar', 'Jahr': 2009, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 35, 'Schauspielern': ["Zoe Saldana","Sigourney Weaver","Sam Worthington"]},
         '6': {'Titel': 'The Devil Wears Prada', 'Jahr': 2006, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ["Meryl Streep","Anne Hathaway","Simon Baker"]},
         '7': {'Titel': 'Submarine', 'Jahr': 2010, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ["Craig Roberts","Yasmin Paige","Sally Hawkins"]},
         '8': {'Titel': 'About Time', 'Jahr': 2013, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 37, 'Schauspielern': ["Margot Robbie","Rachel McAdams","Domhnall Gleeson"]},
         '9': {'Titel': 'Love, Rosie', 'Jahr': 2014, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 25, 'Schauspielern': ["Lily Collins","Sam Claflin","Christian Cooke"]},
        '10': {'Titel': 'Me Before You', 'Jahr': 2016, 'Wertung': 9, 'Preis': 45, 'Schauspielern': ["Emilia Clarke","Sam Claflin","Matthew Lewis"]}
    }`
```

I have  to sort it so that it displays only the movies containing a specific actor. I have tried creating a list with 3 actors (which are introduced by the user) to compare with each of the other lists. If there was any common actor found, the movie (with all the speific info) would be stored in another dictionary and eventually printed.

Here's the code I've tried implementing:

```
Spielern = []

for x in range(3):
    Spieler = input("Schauspieler: ")
    Spielern.append(Spieler)

print(Spielern)

new_dict = {}
for element in Spielern:
    if element in Schauspielern:
        new_dict.update(Filme[element])

for x in new_dict:
    print(x)
    for y in new_dict[x]:
        print(y, ':', new_dict[x][y])

print(new_dict)
```

But it's not working and I can't really figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated, considering that I'm quite a beginner in Python programming.

Comment: this is the second time you ask this today, right?

Comment: Doesn't that code raise `NameError` on Schauspielern?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis it's not the same thing, I wouldn't have asked if I knew how to solve it

Comment: @PM2Ring it says it's not defined

Comment: `if element in Schauspielern` would not work in this code, you need to iterate over `Filme` and then check the dictionary-key `Schauspielern`.
The code above is non-working code. Please post either running code or non-running code with a specific error and what exactly you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of queries helping you to achieve what you want:

```
import itertools

Filme = {
    '1': {'Titel': 'Titanic', 'Jahr': 1997, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 30, 'Schauspielern': ["Leonardo Dicaprio", "Kate Winslet", "Gloria Stuart"]},
    '2': {'Titel': 'Pulp Fiction', 'Jahr': 1994, 'Wertung': 9, 'Preis': 40, 'Schauspielern': ["Uma Thurman", "John Travolta", "Quentin Tarantion"]},
    '3': {'Titel': 'Wings of Desire', 'Jahr': 1987, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 40, 'Schauspielern': ["Bruno Ganz", "Peter Falk", "Otto Sander"]},
    '4': {'Titel': 'London Has Fallen', 'Jahr': 2016, 'Wertung': 6, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ["Gerald Butler", "Morgan Freeman", "Aaron Eckhart"]},
    '5': {'Titel': 'Avatar', 'Jahr': 2009, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 35, 'Schauspielern': ["Zoe Saldana", "Sigourney Weaver", "Sam Worthington"]},
    '6': {'Titel': 'The Devil Wears Prada', 'Jahr': 2006, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ["Meryl Streep", "Anne Hathaway", "Simon Baker"]},
    '7': {'Titel': 'Submarine', 'Jahr': 2010, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ["Craig Roberts", "Yasmin Paige", "Sally Hawkins"]},
    '8': {'Titel': 'About Time', 'Jahr': 2013, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 37, 'Schauspielern': ["Margot Robbie", "Rachel McAdams", "Domhnall Gleeson"]},
    '9': {'Titel': 'Love, Rosie', 'Jahr': 2014, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 25, 'Schauspielern': ["Lily Collins", "Sam Claflin", "Christian Cooke"]},
    '10': {'Titel': 'Me Before You', 'Jahr': 2016, 'Wertung': 9, 'Preis': 45, 'Schauspielern': ["Emilia Clarke", "Sam Claflin", "Matthew Lewis"]}
}


def flatten_list(lst):
    return list(
        itertools.chain(*[([v] if isinstance(v, str) else v) for v in lst]))


def get_movies_by_actor(data, actor):
    return [row['Titel'] for key, row in data.items() if actor in row['Schauspielern']]


def get_actors(data):
    return set(flatten_list([row['Schauspielern'] for key, row in data.items()]))

for actor in sorted(get_actors(Filme)):
    print('actor={: <20} films=[{}]'.format(
        actor, ",".join(get_movies_by_actor(Filme, actor))))
```

output:

```
actor=Aaron Eckhart        films=[London Has Fallen]
actor=Anne Hathaway        films=[The Devil Wears Prada]
actor=Bruno Ganz           films=[Wings of Desire]
actor=Christian Cooke      films=[Love, Rosie]
actor=Craig Roberts        films=[Submarine]
actor=Domhnall Gleeson     films=[About Time]
actor=Emilia Clarke        films=[Me Before You]
actor=Gerald Butler        films=[London Has Fallen]
actor=Gloria Stuart        films=[Titanic]
actor=John Travolta        films=[Pulp Fiction]
actor=Kate Winslet         films=[Titanic]
actor=Leonardo Dicaprio    films=[Titanic]
actor=Lily Collins         films=[Love, Rosie]
actor=Margot Robbie        films=[About Time]
actor=Matthew Lewis        films=[Me Before You]
actor=Meryl Streep         films=[The Devil Wears Prada]
actor=Morgan Freeman       films=[London Has Fallen]
actor=Otto Sander          films=[Wings of Desire]
actor=Peter Falk           films=[Wings of Desire]
actor=Quentin Tarantion    films=[Pulp Fiction]
actor=Rachel McAdams       films=[About Time]
actor=Sally Hawkins        films=[Submarine]
actor=Sam Claflin          films=[Love, Rosie,Me Before You]
actor=Sam Worthington      films=[Avatar]
actor=Sigourney Weaver     films=[Avatar]
actor=Simon Baker          films=[The Devil Wears Prada]
actor=Uma Thurman          films=[Pulp Fiction]
actor=Yasmin Paige         films=[Submarine]
actor=Zoe Saldana          films=[Avatar]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed not **exactly** the same but very similar.. Anyway, you did show some effort with your code. Take a look at the code below. I have converted your loops to `list-comprehensions` for aesthetic reasons.

```
Spielern = [input("Schauspieler: ") for _ in range(3)]
print(Spielern)

new_dict = {k: v for k, v in Filme.items() if any(x in v['Schauspielern'] for x in Spielern)}
print(new_dict)

for k, v in new_dict.items():
    print(k)
    for subK, subV in v.items():
        print(" {}: {}".format(subK, subV))
```

The problem with your code was `Schauspielern` that was used as a variable name when it actually should be used as a `dictionary` `key`.

Test run:

In::

```
Schauspieler:  Leonardo Dicaprio
Schauspieler:  Peter Falk
Schauspieler:  Bruno Ganz
```

Out::

```
1
  Titel: Titanic
  Jahr: 1997
  Wertung: 8
  Preis: 30
  Schauspielern: ['Leonardo Dicaprio', 'Kate Winslet', 'Gloria Stuart']
3
  Titel: Wings of Desire
  Jahr: 1987
  Wertung: 8
  Preis: 40
  Schauspielern: ['Bruno Ganz', 'Peter Falk', 'Otto Sander']
```

Comment: @Adirio I initially left that part of the code unchanged.

Comment: May I also suggest: `print("  {}: {}".format(subK, subV))`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the `Filme` dictionary and check if the actor list in each film intersects with the set of actors that you're searching for.

```
from pprint import pprint

Filme = {
'1': {'Jahr': 1997,
       'Preis': 30,
       'Schauspielern': ['Leonardo Dicaprio', 'Kate Winslet', 'Gloria Stuart'],
       'Titel': 'Titanic',
       'Wertung': 8},
 '10': {'Jahr': 2016,
        'Preis': 45,
        'Schauspielern': ['Emilia Clarke', 'Sam Claflin', 'Matthew Lewis'],
        'Titel': 'Me Before You',
        'Wertung': 9},
 '2': {'Jahr': 1994,
       'Preis': 40,
       'Schauspielern': ['Uma Thurman', 'John Travolta', 'Quentin Tarantion'],
       'Titel': 'Pulp Fiction',
       'Wertung': 9},
 '3': {'Jahr': 1987,
       'Preis': 40,
       'Schauspielern': ['Bruno Ganz', 'Peter Falk', 'Otto Sander'],
       'Titel': 'Wings of Desire',
       'Wertung': 8},
 '4': {'Jahr': 2016,
       'Preis': 20,
       'Schauspielern': ['Gerald Butler', 'Morgan Freeman', 'Aaron Eckhart'],
       'Titel': 'London Has Fallen',
       'Wertung': 6},
 '5': {'Jahr': 2009,
       'Preis': 35,
       'Schauspielern': ['Zoe Saldana', 'Sigourney Weaver', 'Sam Worthington'],
       'Titel': 'Avatar',
       'Wertung': 8},
 '6': {'Jahr': 2006,
       'Preis': 20,
       'Schauspielern': ['Meryl Streep', 'Anne Hathaway', 'Simon Baker'],
       'Titel': 'The Devil Wears Prada',
       'Wertung': 7},
 '7': {'Jahr': 2010,
       'Preis': 20,
       'Schauspielern': ['Craig Roberts', 'Yasmin Paige', 'Sally Hawkins'],
       'Titel': 'Submarine',
       'Wertung': 7},
 '8': {'Jahr': 2013,
       'Preis': 37,
       'Schauspielern': ['Margot Robbie', 'Rachel McAdams', 'Domhnall Gleeson'],
       'Titel': 'About Time',
       'Wertung': 8},
 '9': {'Jahr': 2014,
       'Preis': 25,
       'Schauspielern': ['Lily Collins', 'Sam Claflin', 'Christian Cooke'],
       'Titel': 'Love, Rosie',
       'Wertung': 7}
}

Spielern = {'Leonardo Dicaprio', 'Uma Thurman', 'Meryl Streep'}

new_filme = {k:v for k,v in Filme.items() if Spielern.intersection(v['Schauspielern'])}
pprint(new_filme)
```

**output**

```
{'1': {'Jahr': 1997,
       'Preis': 30,
       'Schauspielern': ['Leonardo Dicaprio', 'Kate Winslet', 'Gloria Stuart'],
       'Titel': 'Titanic',
       'Wertung': 8},
 '2': {'Jahr': 1994,
       'Preis': 40,
       'Schauspielern': ['Uma Thurman', 'John Travolta', 'Quentin Tarantion'],
       'Titel': 'Pulp Fiction',
       'Wertung': 9},
 '6': {'Jahr': 2006,
       'Preis': 20,
       'Schauspielern': ['Meryl Streep', 'Anne Hathaway', 'Simon Baker'],
       'Titel': 'The Devil Wears Prada',
       'Wertung': 7}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You can test it here https://repl.it/Nob0/0

```
Spielern = []

for x in range(3):
    Spieler = input("Schauspieler: ")
    Spielern.append(Spieler)

new_dict = list({})
for film in Filme:
    print(film)
    for schauspieler in Spielern:
      if schauspieler in Filme[film]["Schauspielern"]:
        if Filme[film] not in new_dict:
          new_dict.append(Filme[film])



print(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Spielern = []

for x in range(3):
   Spieler = input("Schauspieler: ")
   Spielern.append(Spieler)

Filme = {'1': {'Titel': 'Titanic', 'Jahr': 1997, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 30, 'Schauspielern': ["Leonardo Dicaprio", "Kate Winslet", "Gloria Stuart"]},
     '2': {'Titel': 'Pulp Fiction', 'Jahr': 1994, 'Wertung': 9, 'Preis': 40, 'Schauspielern': ["Uma Thurman","John Travolta","Quentin Tarantion"]},
     '3': {'Titel': 'Wings of Desire', 'Jahr': 1987, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 40, 'Schauspielern': ["Bruno Ganz","Peter Falk","Otto Sander"]},
     '4': {'Titel': 'London Has Fallen', 'Jahr': 2016, 'Wertung': 6, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ["Gerald Butler","Morgan Freeman","Aaron Eckhart"]},
     '5': {'Titel': 'Avatar', 'Jahr': 2009, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 35, 'Schauspielern': ["Zoe Saldana","Sigourney Weaver","Sam Worthington"]},
     '6': {'Titel': 'The Devil Wears Prada', 'Jahr': 2006, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ["Meryl Streep","Anne Hathaway","Simon Baker"]},
     '7': {'Titel': 'Submarine', 'Jahr': 2010, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 20, 'Schauspielern': ["Craig Roberts","Yasmin Paige","Sally Hawkins"]},
     '8': {'Titel': 'About Time', 'Jahr': 2013, 'Wertung': 8, 'Preis': 37, 'Schauspielern': ["Margot Robbie","Rachel McAdams","Domhnall Gleeson"]},
     '9': {'Titel': 'Love, Rosie', 'Jahr': 2014, 'Wertung': 7, 'Preis': 25, 'Schauspielern': ["Lily Collins","Sam Claflin","Christian Cooke"]},
    '10': {'Titel': 'Me Before You', 'Jahr': 2016, 'Wertung': 9, 'Preis': 45, 'Schauspielern': ["Emilia Clarke","Sam Claflin","Matthew Lewis"]}
}

final_movies = {a:b for a, b in Filme.items() if any(i in b['Schauspielern'] for i in Spielern)}
```